# is $T = \frac{d}{dx}$ continuous on the space of continuously differentiable functions on an interval?

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose we are in the space $C^{\infty}[a, b]$ and we are using the infinity norm (i.e. $max_{[a, b]}|f(x)|$).  Is the differentiation operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ continuous on the space?  I want to say yes, but I can't construct a convincing argument (proof) as to why.

I know that continuity in this context means that if I have a convergent sequence in the space $\{f_n\}$ where $f_n \rightarrow f$ then $\frac{d}{dx}f_n \rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}f$

Comment: No, you can create functions that are bounded by a small $\epsilon$ but whose derivatives become large, say a sine wave with small amplitude but very high frequency.

Comment: ... i.e., let $f_n(x)=\frac1n\sin n^2x$

Comment: This is one way of seeing that the infinity norm is the "wrong" topology on $C^\infty([a,b])$.

Answer (score 5):

No.  Consider the sequence of functions defined by
$$
f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \cos (n^2 x).
$$
on $[0, 2\pi]$. We have $ \max |f_n(x)| = \frac{1}{n}$, but $\max|f'_n(x)| = n$.  Thus, $f_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, but $f'_n$ diverges.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I didn't consider trig functions.